# Why is this code trying to open json file for pickle purpose giving "No such file or directory: 'file name'"?

Tags: python, file-io, neural-network, pickle

I am actually trying to read my json file for pickle purpose but it show No such file or directory: 'conversation'. What should i do? Should I convert my json file to what?

This is my code:

```
import os
import pickle
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
import gensim
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM,SimpleRNN
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import theano
theano.config.optimizer="None"

with open('conversation.pickle') as f:
    vec_x,vec_y=pickle.load(f)    

vec_x=np.array(vec_x,dtype=np.float64)
vec_y=np.array(vec_y,dtype=np.float64)
```

My error is:

```
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/thesemicolon-master/chatbotlstmtrain.py", line 18, in <module>
    with open('conversation') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conversation'
```

But I had double confirmed there's a conversation.json file in my folder, please help and thank you !

Comment: `conversation.pickle` ≠ `conversation` ≠ `conversation.json`

Comment: in your code snippet you have `conversation.pickle`, in your error you just have `conversation` and in your comment you confirm the file `conversation.json` exists... which one is it?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code.

Comment: the code doesn't tally with the error, nut l would say in the file where you have conversation.json change your file referencing style from "C:/users/xx/conversation.json" to "./conversation.json" in the python script

Comment: my code is actually got from here and im also confusing cuz leak of explanation and im still a student with poor programming language and nid your help so badly. https://github.com/shreyans29/thesemicolon

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_pickle("conversation.json")
```

or

```
with open("conversation.json.pickle") as f:
    vec_x,vec_y=pickle.load(f)
```

or add full path of conversation.json

Comment: Hi thank you ! but after i tried this another error show 
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/thesemicolon-master/chatbotlstmtrain.py", line 18
    vec_x,vec_y=pickle.load(f)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @LihYao Do not copy paste the code. Type it out and check the indentation. The error you are getting is a indentation error

Comment: Hmmm im not sure is it working now since the error a bit diff now, yea its IndentationError now but i saw no prob in my code also..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the sample code you're working with expects you to first run the script [`chatbotPreprocessing.py`](https://github.com/shreyans29/thesemicolon/blob/master/chatbotPreprocessing.py) which reads in the file `conversation.json` (which appears to have some sample "conversations" as training data) , and it outputs the file `conversation.pickle` which contains some results of running some preprocessing tokenization of the conversation data.

(Incidentally this is not a very well written script for several reasons, amongst which includes the fact that it contains an `os.chdir()` to some hard-coded path. Typical for researcher code but not good for sharing you code with other people who might be running it on a different computer. You can just delete this line, as long as you run the script from within the same directory as the code and data files).